# Deleting nodes from a linked list recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

Given a linked list and a specified data value, I want to delete all nodes with the said data recursively. (I already figured out how to do it iteratively, but I want to do it this way). I have defined my structs as:

```
struct Node{
  int data;
  Node *next;
};
struct LinkedList{
  Node *head;
};
```

To do the deleting, I made this helper function, which (should) return the pointer to the head node of my deleted list:

```
Node* deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper(Node *head, int value){
  if (head==NULL){
    return 0;
  }
  if (head->data==value){
    head=head->next;
    deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper(head,value);
    return 0;
  } else{
    Node *x=head;
    deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper(head->next,value);
    return x;
  }
}
```

and then I want to use it on my actual list:

```
void deleteNodeRecursively(LinkedList* list, int value){
  if (list->head==NULL){
    return;
  } else if (list->head->data==value){
    list->head=list->head->next;
    deleteNodeRecursively(list,value);
   } else{
    deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper(list->head->next,value);
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. It looks like my helper function doesn't actually work but I can't figure it out. What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you doing homework? Saw the same question & code in another question earlier today. Try hard to complete your homework, please.

Comment: Try a simple recursive function ..analyze the call stack ..that may help to understand

Comment: `deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper` does three kinds of things: It returns a value, it sets local variables, and it calls itself (doing more of the same). Local variables are gone as soon as the function returns, so calling `deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper` has no effect. In addition, every call to this function ignores its return value, so your helper function is effectively pointless. It might as well return `void` and be empty.

Comment: Invest time in learning the use of debugging software. It will save you great amounts of time. A debugger allows you to control the execution of your program, executing line by line; until an event occurs; and sometimes even executing backward, and inspect the state of the program, the variables, while you do so. A debugger should have come with your development environment. If not, consider getting a different development environment. The debugging tools that come with the free versions of Visual Studio are excellent.

Comment: You might find it easier to recurse to the end of the list (`head==NULL`) and perform the deleting on the way back.

Comment: Oh, and if you have no debugger and can't easily switch development environments, there are nifty little tools like https://www.onlinegdb.com/ scattered around the Internet.

Comment: Forgot the most important rule of linked lists: Draw them. Draw the list on a piece of paper. Work through the paper list performing whatever operation you are working on and take notes of what you have to do in order to get the results you want. Organize your notes and transform them into the logic you need to code.

Comment: I've demonstrated a similar Java solution for a singly list in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485863/1272886

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
Node* deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper(Node* head, int value){
    if (head == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (head->data == value) {
        auto next = head->next;
        delete head; // I assume that you allocate node.
        return deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper(next, value);
    } else {
        head->next = deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper(head->next, value);
        return head;
    }
}

void deleteNodeRecursively(LinkedList* list, int value){
    list->head = deleteNodeRecursivelyHelper(list->head, value);
}
```